# How Can We Get Token And Show It In Response

Tags: cypress, web-api-testing

I have one request that I want to get token from response and save it in variable because I want to use it in another request as bearer token

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
describe("Testing API Endpoints Using Cypress", () => {
    it("Login", () => {
        cy.request({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/creditonal",
            body: {
                "credentials": {
                    "username": "admin",
                    "password": "admin"
                }
            }.then((response) => {
                // Get token
            })
        })
    })
})
```

This is my response

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "statusCode": "0000",
    "message": {
        "type": "",
        "text": ""
    },
    "errors": [],
    "data": {
        "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVmYTk0YzYzNWRhOWU0NTY0NGYwM2ViMiIsImlzQ2xpZW50IjpmYWxzZSwiaWF0IjoxNjExMjQzNjYyLCJleHBBdCI6MTYxMTI0NzI2MiwiaXNzdWVyIjoiRHJvcHAgVGVjaG5vbG9naWVzIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiRVJ5eGc2Il19.V7cniqE9DrxPRn5GX9wQJtVwPnLrv5Hb3A1SxmBXOO4",
        "accessTokenExpiresAt": 3599,
        "refreshToken": "983e503a2b194a0190af4cdf0f4d471cf387e4d784044f6ca1fe3f942aad1b5f",
        "refreshTokenExpiresAt": 15548399
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the response JSON that your getting.

Comment: i add it to quesiton

Answer (score 0):

You can use token from from request 1 and pass it onto request 2 like this. I have currently used the token as an [bearer authorization header](https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication).

```
cy.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/creditonal",
    body: {
        "credentials": {
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin"
        }
    }
}).then((response) => {
    const token = response.data.accessToken
    return token
}).then((token) => {
    //Use the value of token anywhere in the second request anywhere
    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https//example.com',
        'auth': {
            'bearer': token
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for `alias` which is easier to use. You just retrieve the response whenever you really need:

```js
it("Login", () => {
  cy.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/creditonal",
    body: {
      "credentials": {
        "username": "admin",
        "password": "admin"
      }
    }
  }).as('login')

   // do more things

  cy.get('@login').then(response => {
    // whatever you want with response later on
  })
})
```